# swift black lines in border viewcontroller

Tags: swift

i have a structure : [Navigation Controller] -> [UITabBarController] -> [VC]

```
let viewcontroller =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "coVC")
    cotViewcontroller.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Rj", image: UIImage(named: "tab1"), selectedImage: nil)

let tabbarController = CircleBarController()
tabbarController.viewControllers = [viewcontroller, ...]
tabbarController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
let tabnavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabbarController)
tabnavigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(tabnavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but in vc i have a black lines. How to remove it ?

[image]

Comment: Use the View Debugger to figure out what the black is. It is probably some view showing through from behind. You might need to set the window's background color to white.

Comment: @matt setting the window's background color to white didnt work ( If i use `[UITabBarController] -> [Navigation Controller] -> [VC]` - i dont have a black lines, but i need to use  [Navigation Controller] -> [UITabBarController] -> [VC]

Comment: Well I've told you how to figure it out. And I suppose you know that a tab bar controller inside a navigation controller is unsupported...

Comment: @matt do u mean that scheme `[Navigation Controller] -> [UITabBarController] -> [VC]` is not correct ? i want to do swipe back like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdycl.jpg) - Pushed UIViewController above UITabBar (if i use `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` vc will be not above UITabBar)

Comment: if i use `[Navigation Controller] -> [UITabBarController] -> [VC]` then i can push vc like this `self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)` and when i will be swipe back Pushed UIViewController will be above UITabBar

Comment: @matt it's not correct ?